# Tensorflow optimizer getting poor results

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to solve various linear regression problems. I get excellent results using the older estimator API `tf.estimator.LinearRegressor`. But I am consistently getting poor quality result when using the new optimizer API (Ftrl, Adam etc). I feel I must be doing something wrong. I have created a [Google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1H9Ho_tovSPEM1voSlwW5hRhVcck5xYzS?usp=sharing) that exhibits the issue using the Ames Housing Price prediction problem. As you will see the estimator gives RMS error about 0.03. The Ftrl optimizer produces a RMS error of about 0.5.

The core optimizer code that I used for all problems is like this. Am I doing something obviously wrong here? Or does `tf.estimator.LinearRegressor` do something extra that I am not doing.

```py
# Create the variables
def model_weights_opt(num_features):
  W = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([num_features, 1], 
                    stddev=0.1, dtype=tf.dtypes.float64))
  b = tf.Variable(0.0, dtype=tf.dtypes.float64)

  return W, b

#Perform prediction
def model_predict_opt(x, W, b):
  return tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W), b)

#Do training
def model_train_opt(train_x, train_y, W, b):
  opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Ftrl(learning_rate=0.02)

  def loss_function():
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(model_predict_opt(train_x, W, b) - train_y))

  #Run training
  for epoch in range(2000):
    opt.minimize(loss_function, var_list=[W, b])

    if epoch % 100 == 0:
      print("Epoch:", epoch, "Loss:", loss_function().numpy())


#Create weight variables
W, b = model_weights_opt(num_features)

#Start training
model_train_opt(train_x.values, train_y.values, W, b)
```

Comment: Different optimizer works in a different way and is suitable for different types of data. Along with the choice of the optimizer, the final loss is also dependent on your initial weights.

Comment: tf.estimator.LinearRegressor uses Ftrl by default. I am using the same optimizer. So it is an apples to apple comparison.